# Extract specific field from json and deserialize it according to speicific Class<?>

Tags: java, json, jackson, mongo-jackson-mapper

I have a piece of json string which I would like to extract specific fields, and it field exist I would like to deserialize it into a specific type (Class).

So far I have tried using ObjectMapper, but the problem with it that it designed to work in a way that the input json value is mapped to a designated class type. and in my case I need to take specific fields out of json string and deserialize them to objects.

Next, I've tried JsonParser, it offers more options since I can iterate over a json field-by-field and for each field call 'readValueAs' method. this is almost perfect for me, my problem is that I don't want to go over the json field-by-field, I would like to dynamically tell the parser which field to parse and only then deserialize it into an object.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

Say I have this json `{ "name" : "Bob", "age" : 21, "status" : false }`

I would like only to extract "name"'s value (Bob) and then deserialize it to
java.lang.String

How can I do this??

EDIT:
I try to describe my flow better:
When the app first loads I read the arguments of a specific method using reflection, later when the app receives a json message I would like to parse the message in a way that every key in the json corresponds to one arguments of the method. so I need to deserialize the value of the key from json into an object that matches that argument.

If you know reflection mechanism in JAVA-8 you can get the type of the argument as well as it's name like you wrote it in the code!

Hope this make it clearer....not sure :-)

Comment: You can deserialize your JSON as Map or JsonNode and then extract the necessary fields.

Comment: I can get the field as JsonNode, but this class doesn't expose a method similar to:
    public <T> T readValueAs(Class<T> valueType)

Comment: I only know the type at runtime so I cannot use the functionality of JsonNode.

Comment: You can convert the JsonNode to an object using ObjectMapper#treeToValue method.

Comment: Eventually I've found the answer thanks to your help!!!  The correct method of doing what I needed is ObjectMapper#convertValue, it takes an object and return an object of type Class<T>. it does it in 2 steps: 1st convert the object into json representation and 2nd step is serializing it into Class<T>.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I've found the answer thanks to the help I've received!!!

The correct method of doing what I needed is `ObjectMapper#convertValue`, it takes an object and return an object of type Class. it does it in 2 steps: 1st convert the object into json representation and 2nd step is serializing it into Class.